# working as java application not as android application

Tags: android

I am reading a json file from a local drive and making it as gson. And it's working as a java application.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\AircraftService.json"));
    DataObject[] obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject[].class);
    System.out.println("The object length is: " + obj.length);
    for(int i = 0; i<obj.length ; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println(obj[i].AC + "  " + obj[i].Fleet + " " + obj[i].SubFleet);
    }
```

Using this I am trying to populate an android list

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\AircraftService.json"));

DataObject[] obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject[].class);
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
for(int i=0 ; i<obj.length ; i++){      

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("AC",  obj[i].AC);
    map.put("Fleet", obj[i].Fleet );
    map.put("SubFleet", obj[i].SubFleet );
    fillMaps.add(map);
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.main, new String[] {"AC", "Fleet"}, new int[] {R.id.ac, R.id.fleet});  
lv.setAdapter(adapter);  
}
```

It's not able to populate the obj. Ouput is blank. Can you tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your file does not reside in `D:\AircraftService.json` on your android device.
Adjust the path, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to your SD-card or flash-memory if you stored your file there. If you stored it inside your apps asset folder, use `file:///android_asset/` as your base path and append the file name (and subfolders).

---

Edit: Considering your comment down below, here's a short howto.

First of all I recommend storing the file in your assets, since reading the sdcard requires a seperate permission for your app.

Theres a folder in your project thats called `res/`. Create a subfolder into that, name it `raw`. Thats a standard android naming convention for storing files that are not standard resources (like layouts or strings). After that you should be able to access the file with the path `file:///android_asset/raw/AircraftService.json`

Comment: oh ... that means android app is not finding the file as it's on local drive and not on device. Is that right?

Comment: Right, the app cant find the file. You have to change the path, depending on where you stored it. This involves copying the file to the device at all, in case you didn't do that yet.

Comment: I did that. But it's still not reading that file. Is something wrong with "DataObject[] obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject[].class);"

Answer (score 0):

The path of the json file cannot be opened. Try moving the file lets say in `assets folder` than open it.

Comment: Tried .. BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("file://android_assets/AircraftService.JASON"));                                                                                        not working

Comment: InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(myJsonfile);

Comment: looks like now I will need to explore io please help...            InputStream instream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("file:///assets/AircraftService.JSON");FileReader reader = (FileReader) new InputStreamReader(instream); NOT WORKING BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); //convert the json string back to object DataObject[] obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject[].class);

Comment: String filename = "myjson.json";
InputStream instream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(filename);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. As I am using "DataObject[] obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject[].class);" I have to have a BufferedReader - br. How can I get that from InputStream ?